# DOMException while cloning XML Node

Tags: xml, android, exception, dom

The cloneNode() method in the following minimal example works on java 1.6 but throws an DOMException with code 14 under android 5.

Code 14 according to sdk docs means:
"NAMESPACE_ERR
If an attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces."

Has anybody an idea why this might be?
Thank you in advance!

```
public class M
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  try
  {
             DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
             DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

             String text = new String("<blub></blub>");
             Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource( new StringReader(text) ));

             document.getDocumentElement().cloneNode(true);
  }
  catch(DOMException e)
  {}
  catch(ParserConfigurationException e)
  {}
  catch(IOException e)
  {}
  catch(SAXException e)
  {}
 }
}
```

Comment: I notice that you ignore 4 different types of exceptions. If you throw away DOMException, I wonder how you know that this is the exception you get, or in what line. In a test application like this, you may wish to throw exceptions from main instead of writing empty handlers:  
`public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {}`.  
You can then see stack traces when you run your code.


It is not clear from your description which statement throws your DOMException.

Comment: You can try to play with factory.setNamespaceAware()

Comment: Thanks I checked already, but unfortunately factory.setNamespaceAware() does not have any influence. I wonder if anybody else can reproduce the problem?


Btw: I know what exception I get because I use exception breakpoints in eclipse or just single step through the code. If I would "ignore" the exception, how would I know about the state of the code property inside the exception object e?
And what line throws the exception is written in the first line of my question: "The cloneNode() method [...] throws [...]"

Comment: One positive intention of a full stack trace is to aid debugging exceptions when I don't have access to your Eclipse breakpoints. Including a stack trace in your report does not guarantee an answer, but it does convey more information with less ambiguity that an English description. Also, some stack traces come with useful message strigns.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known bug with both cloneNode and importNode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8438416/671393

The "workaround" is to use adoptNode instead, but obviously this will modify the source DOM.

This bug is fixed in later versions: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2735#c4

If the bug is indeed due to nodes not being namespace aware (as suggested in the bug report), then the addition of a dummy namespace might be another workaround.